# `unrecognized selector sent to instance <OBJ_ADR>`after sending `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` to a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, dismiss, unrecognized-selector

Lots of similar questions but non with a solution that works in my case.

I try to write a simple FlipSideApp. Just two views with a single button each (flipBtn | flopBtn) to present the other view vice versa.
`flip` on the first view works fine. `flop` on the other view causes a
`unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c3adf0`.

The App crashes after calling `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`  in file **FlipSide.m** (see code below). Where `0x6c3adf0` is the current address of `self` which is an instance of `FlipSide : UIViewController` in that case.

So I think the unrecognized selector mentioned in the error message is the `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion`-method.
While typing Xcode's CodeSense "recommends" that method.

According to the *UIViewController Class Reference* this method is known in iOS 5.0 SDK.
My Deployment Target is 5.0, Device iPhone,  Base SDK iOS 5.0, Architecture Standard (arm7).

With a symbolic breakpoint set for all Exceptions the debugger stops at UIApplicationMain in main function. Which is nothing that give me a hint.
Zombie-Objects are enabled. Even when I think memory leaks are not the problem here.

What can I do that makes the selector be recognized?

File: "**AppDelegate.m**"

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application  
                  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc]  
                      initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc]  
                 initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.window.rootViewController = viewController1;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

---

File: "**FirstViewController.h**"

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)flipBtn:(id)sender;

@end
```

File: "**FirstViewController.m**"

```
…
- (IBAction)flipBtn:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"%s -- reached --", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

FlipSide* flipSide = [[FlipSide alloc] initWithNibName:@"FLipSide" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:flipSide animated:YES completion:nil];    

NSLog(@"%s -- done --", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

---

File: "**FlipSide.h**"

```
@interface FlipSide : UIViewController 

- (IBAction)flopBtn:(id)sender;

@end
```

File: "**FlipSide.m**"

```
#import "FlipSide.h"

- (IBAction)flopBtn:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"%s -- reached --", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

NSLog(@"self address is: %@", self);

//  //  //      ??? unrecognized selector sent to instance ???
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //  <--

NSLog(@"%s -- done --", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

---

**Console** OutPut is:

```
-[FirstViewController flipBtn:] -- reached --
-[FirstViewController flipBtn:] -- done --
-[FLipSide flopBtn:] -- reached --
self address is: <FLipSide 0x6c3adf0>
-[FLipSide flopBtn:] -- done --
-[FLipSide flopBtn:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c3adf0
```

Comment: Try `[self.navigationController dismissView...]` instead. I've encountered weird memory issues if you call it on the `UIViewController` instead of the `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I am sorry that does not help it.  
  
My app still crashes with the same error message

Comment: I experimented a little and found out something:  
  
(1) I implemented the exactly same project once again with Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) enabled. That made the (exactly same) code working.  
  
(2) After that I shutdown my computer, restarted it and implemented the (exactly same) source code another time but WITHOUT ARC again like I did in the very first time.  

The unbelievable thing is: After running an ARC enabled project and a shut down my computer. Now the project (itself has still no ARC enabled) runs without errors, warning, problems or that original error message. Why???

Comment: If you re-implemented your code a second time, and it started working, it (barring any really weird edge cases) just means you had a typo of some sort in your original project.

Comment: I don not think so, cause I copied and pasted the source code (It is just of three lines of code). I would not wonder If copying would cause typos but correcting some? - I'll double check that. --  --  Is there a way to check if ARC is enabled during runtime. Or is there any option to check after creation of a project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the **solution** myself!

Knowing it the error message makes sense:
The answer lies in the used XIB-file(s).

Rule of thumb:
**Check your GUI-Elements in InterfaceBuilder by *right-cklicking* or *"ctrl"+clicking* that all their sent events are connected to existing methods!**

If that is not the case the
`instance` means the GUI element get `sent` a
`unrecognized selector` means a non existing method connected to it in InterfaceBuilder. ;-)

Be aware that one event can be connected to several methods. If even one of them is not defined (any longer) you will get that error.
Keep this in mind if you delete, rename or change signatures of methods manually. The formerly made connection may still exist.

Comment: Would someone please vote for that answer - I can't (_It is forbidden to vote for your own answers_).

Comment: You can accept your own answer after a certain period of time, it doesn't need to be voted for necessarily.

Comment: Thanx - just discovered that will be possible `tomorrow`.